# Click area only once

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of map areas, each time they're clicked they increment a value. I need them to only be clickable once. I've looked at a few posts on here but everything I've tried doesn't work. My latest effort is this one below. Please assist with javascript only.

```
    <map name="m__r30_c11" id="m__r30_c11">
<area shape="poly" coords="12,-5,-19,-25,-32,-19,-48,-4,-55,24,-34,46,-13,53,13,35,19,6" alt="" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar27','n_r29_c6','images/_r29_c6_s4.jpg','n_r29_c11','images/_r29_c11_s4.jpg','n_r30_c11','images/_r30_c11_s4.jpg',1); incrementValue(); this.disabled=true;">
</map>
```

I need something that will work in the onclick if possible, because they're not all map areas

Otherwise, can I disable the onclick for that area in the incrementValue function somehow? I tried but couldn't work it out.

```
    function incrementValue()
{
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('score').value);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
document.getElementById('score').value = value;
}
```

Comment: Anyone needs something. What have you tried so far?

Comment: praying...just joking... I tried a few things, most of which I barely understood and none of which worked

Comment: @AhmadAlfy Not everyone - refer to [Nikola Tesla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla) achievements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the inline onclick syntax, you can use the following to set your `onclick` to null after the first click, so subsequent clicks no longer trigger anything:

```
onclick="incrementValue(); this.onclick=null;"
```

In your code, it would look like this:

```
<map name="m__r30_c11" id="m__r30_c11">
<area shape="poly" coords="12,-5,-19,-25,-32,-19,-48,-4,-55,24,-34,46,-13,53,13,35,19,6" alt="" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar27','n_r29_c6','images/_r29_c6_s4.jpg','n_r29_c11','images/_r29_c11_s4.jpg','n_r30_c11','images/_r30_c11_s4.jpg',1); incrementValue(); this.onclick=null;">
</map>
```

And here is a **live demo** of this method applied to a standard HTML button:

```js
function incrementValue() {
    /* Your other code here */
    alert("this only happens once");
}
```

```html
<button id="thebutton" onclick="incrementValue(); this.onclick=null;">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `this.onclick='';` instead of `this.disabled=true;` removing the onclick as desired, no onclick no response to click.

Comment: no luck, am I getting the syntax correct? ; incrementValue(); this.onclick='';">